# Conditional Formatting in merged cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

guys, I'm trying to do some crazy things in Google Sheets and I'm getting in trouble. Can someone help me?
I have [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvDg0DuuUR7QwlJIqAwgw9BsICgc5TqSnb_T40mI5xk/edit?usp=sharing) with tasks and subtasks. Each subtask has a status (done, in progress or not stated)What I want to do is set one progress for task depending on its subtasks. This way:

- if all subtasks have a status not stated, the task is not stated(red color)
- if all subtasks have a status done, the task is done(green color)
- if all subtasks have a status in progress, the task is in progress (orange color)
- if we have at least one subtasks not stated, the task is not stated. Same for another status

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try separately for A column with those merged cells:

[image: 0]

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, C:C), "Not Started")*(B:B<>"")
```

---

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, C:C), "In Progress")*(B:B<>"")
```

---

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, C:C), "Done")*(B:B<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! Just one more thing... what i do if i have more than one task ?